# Creating JAR file error in netbeans programming assignment

Tags: java

This is my first programming assignment and I am receiving the error message of not finding javadoc when trying to create the file. The instruction stated that I could create the file in the command line and I have tested and run the program with no errors. I have complied the following code lines 1-14 I am being told to create a subclass and am not sure how to do this any help would be highly appreciated!! :

```
// First program in Java
// Sharon Aschermann

public class FirstProgram
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Programming is not a spectator sport!");
    System.out.println("Sharon Aschermann is one of its players.");         
    // Student code ends here
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
jar cf Greeting.jar FirstProgram.class
```

Comment: Hopefully the "jar" command is not part of your source file. *I am receiving the error message* - and the error message is???

Comment: error: class, interface, or enum expected
jar cf Greeting.jar FirstProgram.class

Comment: also: error: reached end of file while parsing
3 errors

Comment: Well, did you read my first sentence? The jar command should NOT be part of the srouce file. "jar" is invoked from the command line to create a ".jar" file. Normally you just use `javac FirstProgram.java` to compile a class and then `java FirstProgram` to test the class.

Comment: the instruction was to type it in this form : jar cf Greeting.jar FirstProgram.class   in the text Im not exactly sure what I am asking so im trying to figure out how to word what i am looking for. i think maybe i am asking what the text is meaning : We can create a JAR file named Greeting.jar from our FirstProgram application by typing the following at the command line: jar cf Greeting.jar FirstProgram.class Note that the input file is the .class file, not the .java file. Figure 1.5 shows the contents of the folder after executing the command above. I am being told to create a subclass

Comment: would i just use the same line without the jar command and replace it with javac???

Comment: OK ... so *"I am receiving the error message of not finding javadoc"* does not make sense to me.  The `jar` command neither knows or cares about javadocs.  So ... if you are really getting that message ... I'm baffled as to what you are actually doinig.

Comment: Step 1, is to compile the source code so you have a class file. Step 2. is to then use the "jar" command to create a .jar file. I have always done it from the command line. I don't know if Netbeans has some special features.